# How to add permanent tooltips or labels to series of Charttype point to a MSChart c#

Tags: c#, charts, tooltip, label, points

I have a chart with series of type "point". I would like to display an additional data near every point, just like toolTip, only I want it permanent and not only on mouse hover.

For example lets say I have a datbase with points, and for each point there is x,y and some unique label. If that is how I display points on my chart:

```
 Series series = new Series("Default");
 series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point; 

for(int i=0; i<datbase.Count; i++)
{
 chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(database[i].x,database[i].y);
}
```

how to get a graph with the points on it, and above each point displayed its unique label?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
Series series = new Series("Default");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point; 

for(int i=0; i<datbase.Count; i++)
{
  int index = chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(database[i].x,database[i].y);
  chart.Series[0].Points[index].Label = "Your Label Text";
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!! I have another small question, how do i edit these labels - color font, etc. I looked for Background or Style property but havent found find any. Thanks.

Comment: try: chart.Series[0].Points[index].LabelForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0);  chart.Series[0].Points[index].Font = New Font("Arial", 16); see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapoint(v=vs.110).aspx for available options